# Bulk enabling Django model field names for translation

Tags: python, django, translation

Is there a way to efficiently include all model field names for translation without manually specifying a `verbose_name` for all of them?

I'm trying to add translation support to a legacy Django app, which has dozens of models, containing hundreds of fields. It seems like an **immense** waste of time to manually change all:

```
my_field = models.SomeField()
```

to:

```
my_field = models.SomeField(verbose_name=_('my field'))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: it would be neat if there were a built in a way, but assuming theres not you could create a script or a search and replace using your favorite command line tools

Comment: @dm03514, Yeah, that's a good point. An alternative idea might be to create a script that reads all my Models, iterates over all fields, and appends the field names to my PO translation file.

Comment: Hmm - I like the idea of writing to the translation file, but wouldn't you still have to change the source code to actually get the translation system to look for them? Or build in a change to the verbose_name resolution behavior.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, Yeah, I just realized that too. Neither of those options are pleasant.

Comment: I've never used this myself, so I can't actually recommend it, but maybe this third party app would be helpful? https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ Hmm - except that it looks like that deals with database content rather than model-level configuration.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, Thanks. You're right in that doesn't look like it would handle static content like model field names. However, on a side note, I'm also looking for ways of translating content stored in models, so that might be useful too.